# ps3 controllers not charging after 2 months

Tags: ps3

Both my dualshock3 controllers are not charging. It's been two months since I last used them as I was relocating. I tried changing the cables, but still, nothing is happening on both. Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: What are you plugging them into in order to charge them?

Comment: How long have you had the controllers? It's possible the batteries are worn out.

Comment: Do the lights blink as though they are charging, but when you try to use them, the system tells you the controller isn't charged? Or do they not blink when charging?